# How to send IOS app made with Phonegap to beta testers

Tags: cordova

I have everything working on my ios development device, but I do not understand how to send the ipa file to beta testers before submitting it to the app store.

I tried installing the ipa file from a website, but the install stops and says the app cannot be installed. I looked at the instructions in the provisioning part of apple's developer site, but I don't understand what I need to do. Some of the steps they detail don't seem to work and/or are geared towards using xcode.

Can anyone provide a step by step on how to do this?

Does the ipa need to be regenerated through phonegap build using different provisioning than the development version?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to create a distribution profile with the UUID of all the beta testing devices. 
Here is a link for instructions to send adhoc build: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app and look for "How Do I Send the Beta Testers an Ad-Hoc Build?"
You donot need to generate `ipa` using `phonegap` build. You can still generate using your machine and ship `ipa` and `mobileprovision` files to beta testers.

Alternatively there is a new emulation available for phonegap: http://emulate.phonegap.com/ which may be another solution.

Comment: It looks like to distribute the app to beta testers using phonegap build 3 things have to be done :

1) Create the adhoc distribution provision
2) Upload the adhoc provision to phonegap build
3) Rebuild the app on phonegap build using the adhoc provisions

Answer (score 0):

I know a number of folks who have used Test Flight successfully.

https://testflightapp.com/

Comment: It looks like testflight is helpful for distributing the app to testers, but you still have to go through the adhoc provisioning process outside of testflight.